# How to run JMTER scripts (JMX) from Java code in a multi-threaded way

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, jmeter

I have created a spring-boot app which can run jmeter scripts (jmx files) and provide me the results. So , basically I am running the jmx through java code using the jmeter lib and it works well for a single user ( I mean , one test at a time). Now , I would to extend this feature for multiple users so that multiple users can run the jmeter engine at the same time using different instances. Please can you let me know how can I achieve this? Note : I have deployed this spring boot app in aws ec-2 instance and have done some brain-storming. Please can you guide me which method I could use

1. Can I de-couple JMeter from Spring boot and run JMETER separately in aws in a multi-threaded way (If so , how is that possible)
2. Can I make my spring-boot app itself multi-threaded. Will that make my Jmeter also to be multi-threaded?

Please enlighten me on this , Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. If your application is just an "entry point" running independent JMeter engines which do the real job on remote machines (one engine - one machine) would be the best option. More information:

   - [RemoteJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/RemoteJMeterEngine.html)
   - [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
2. JMeter tests are quite resource intensive (i.e. see [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean) chapter of JMeter Best Practices) and if your "multiple users" will kick off several tests at the same time they will "fight" for the system resources and you may run into the situation when none of your JMeter engines can really conduct the required load because they don't have enough CPU cycles, RAM or Network throughput. So you either need to ensure that the machine where you run your application is **very** powerful or look for a way of scaling your application (i.e. via [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/))

Comment: Hi Dmitri , Thank you so much for your response on this.  In fact , I was waiting for your comment on this :) 1. Currently , I have bundled the JMeter libs along with my spring-boot app so the machine where I deployed this spring-boot jar itself will act as JMeter engine. In short , my application is not an entry point for running independent JMeter engines but a JMeter engine itself. 2. Based on what you have said , I should be using Remote/Distributed testing and just make a call to JMeter so the tests get executed independently.

Comment: Now , the real question is Will JMeter support "running multiple tests by different users (the user here is the user that triggers the test not threads in jmeter) all at the same time"?.I.e..., The same JMeter engine may be used by multiple users (assuming, the resource utilization is okay) as in BlazeMeter/Performance Center. Will it support? -- All these considering my running the JMeter test from Java Code directly (not using JMeter GUI).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using jemeter to test your app under load (in fact that is whole purpose of jMeter tool). There are two ways you can achieve this

1. Create a threadGroup object inside your spring boot app and setNumThreads(numberOfThreads). It provides below method

   ```
   public static ThreadGroup newInstance(LoopController loopController) {
      ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
      threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
      threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());
      threadGroup.setName("Http URL/API Test");
      threadGroup.setEnabled(true);
      threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
      threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
      threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
      threadGroup.setScheduler(false);
      threadGroup.setDuration(0);
      threadGroup.setDelay(0);
      threadGroup.setComment("");
      threadGroup.setProperty(ThreadGroup.ON_SAMPLE_ERROR, "continue");
   return threadGroup;
   }
   ```
2. Run jMeter in GUI mode separately and put load on your app by configuring thread group.
   This you can do either on your local machine by downloading jMeter or you need to
   figure it out how to run jMeter service on AWS which is a altogether different topic

To answer your questions :

1. Can I de-couple JMeter from Spring boot and run JMETER separately in aws in a multi-
   threaded way (If so , how is that possible) : **Yes you can do it**
2. Can I make my spring-boot app itself multi-threaded. Will that make my Jmeter also to be multi-threaded? : **You should not make any changes to your original app. Just run jMeter with Thread group**

Comment: Hi Datta , Thank you for your response but I think you have misinterpreted my question. I wasn't asking about ThreadGroups/Running JMeter tests but was asking about running multiple JMeter tests all at once on a single JMeter engine.